# What is Quora's logo doing on Stack Overflow's "2018 developer Survey" page as favicon?

Tags: discussion, favicon

I just joined this awesome website today, and I got an email regarding "2018 developer Survey", but I opened the page, I was quite shocked. The favicon of this survey page looked like Quora's logo, ditto! Only, a little of the top was cropped out!
https://stackoverflow.az1.qualtrics.com/favicon.ico

What is the explanation?

Comment: it's a Qualtrics favicon, which appears to be the website they're using to host the survey. It does look like Quora in that it is a red Q.

Comment: The favicon has since changed

Answer (score 12):

That's the Qualtrics favicon.

While very similar, that icon is not the same as the Quora favicon:

Qualtrics:

[image: A red 'Q' with the top and left sides cropped off. The tail of the Q overlaps the circle and the tail end on the inside is connected to the circle.]

Quora:
[image: A red 'Q' with the entire letter visible. The tail of the Q overlaps the circle but neither end is connected to it.]

Comment: This answer doesn't really make sense now since I failed to see how they are similar in any way :)

Comment: Very similar???

Comment: @AndrewT. Qualtrics changed their logo, I updated the answer with their original logo.

Comment: @ShadowWizard quite similar.

Comment: @BhargavRao oh, really too bad neither OP nor author of this answer bothered to post screenshot in that case. :/

Comment: @ShadowWizard which is why you shouldn't assume that companies don't change their logo :p